# How to print URL arguments in headers VIEWS

Tags: views

I have a blog with URL `http:/node/add/blog` and I am using a view discussion board to display the content of blog using VIEWS.

I want to add this URL `http:/node/add/blog` to  Header view. Any idea? How to do it?

Comment: you just want to print this string 'http:/node/add/blog' at top of view? If that is your requirement just add one text area in views header and add that text in that text area. Otherwise please be more specific on your issue. That url is dynamic?

Comment: If you want to print the URL arguments in headers VIEWS then use **PHP code (Global: PHP field)**

Answer (score 0):

You can use arg() function to access the url parameters.

Returns a component of the current Drupal path.

When viewing a page at the path "admin/structure/types", for example, arg(0) returns "admin", arg(1) returns "structure", and arg(2) returns "types".